# как получить сертификат из из хранилища ОС

Tags: c#

Получил задание:
"Получить и проверить цифровую подпись файла, в качестве пары ключей использовать само подписанный сертификат X509 который будет располагаться в хранилище сертификатов операционной системы для доступа к хранилищу использовать X509Store." Нашел как брать сертификат из файла

```
try
{
X509Certificate theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile ("c:\\r\\1.dll");
Console.Write("certificate info :"+ theSigner.GetCertHashString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("No digital signature ");
}
```

а как это сделать из хранилища не знаю. Подскажите, как это сделать.

Comment: Что у вас пока получилось? Добавте код.

Comment: Гуляя по интернету я нашёл только как брать сертификат из файла, а как из хранилища ОС не могу найти

Comment: Здесь не отвечают на вопрос, как написать _программу_: это слишком общий вопрос (думаю, за это и минусы). Здесь могут подсказать по конкретной функциональности.

Answer (score 4):

Для получения доступа к хранилищу вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Выбираем и открываем хранилище с сертификатами
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            //Проходим по всем сертификатам и что то с ними делаем
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                //В данном участке кода будут все сертификаты из указанного хранилища
            }

            //Закрываем хранилище
            store.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

В связи с вполне логичным комментарием товарища **@VladD** дополняю кодом с использованием **using**. Это необходимо для обеспечения закрытия хранилища даже в случае ошибки в блоке обработки сертификатов (И банально это более лаконично).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Выбираем и открываем хранилище с сертификатами
    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        //Проходим по всем сертификатам и что то с ними делаем
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
        {
            //В данном участке кода будут все сертификаты из указанног охранилища
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Если вам требуется реализовать подпись по ГОСТу, то вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой [GostCryptography](https://github.com/AlexMAS/GostCryptography)

Comment: Лучше было бы наверное использовать `using (var store = ...)`?

Comment: @VladD да, я думаю вы правы

Comment: @VladD, дополнил ответ)